# How can I get the adapter name in hubot script?

Tags: hubot

Hubot can support different adapter like Shell/IRC/XMPP.

If the adapter is set in environment variable `HUBOT_ADAPTER`, then `process.env.HUBOT_ADAPTER` can be checked.

```
if process.env.HUBOT_ADAPTER is "shell"
   msg.send "This is Shell adapater"
```

But it also support to use options `--adapter`, and how can I detect this in the hubot script.

I want to write different logic based on adapter like chat-room, userid.

Otherwise I need to prepare separate scripts for different adapater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the two suggestions from github issues https://github.com/github/hubot/issues/647

[**update**] this issue is fixed in source code `robot.coffee` by adding `adapterName`, so you can check `robot.adapterName` since version 2.7.2, see [changes](https://github.com/github/hubot/pull/663/files)

**sniff**, It could be checked with special information in `adapter`, and possible checks below for my environment on `shell`,`xmpp`,`irc`

```js
robot.respond /adapter$/i, (msg) ->
    #console.log "adapter", robot.adapter
    if robot.adapter.client?
        if robot.adapter.client.preferredSaslMechanism?
            msg.send "this is xmpp adapter"
    if robot.adapter.bot?
        if robot.adapter.bot.opt?
            msg.send "this is irc adapter"
        #if robot.adapter.bot?
            #   msg.send "this is campfire ?"
    if robot.adapter.repl?
        if robot.adapter.repl.terminal?
            msg.send "this is shell adapter"
```

**add extra parameter** in `robot.coffee`, it needs a patch for this, it is inside code see update above

I choose **sniff** so far